# Principle in Hand Gesture Design

Tags: gestures, design-principles

I want to design Hand Gesture. By hand gesture, I mean the form or movement made from wrist to the end of your finger, e.g. 'thumb up', 'peace sign', 'waving hand', etc. I design it to be tested on a UI like webpage, e.g. 'peace sign' for action 'going to the next page', 'waving' for 'back to the prev page', etc.

The thing is, this is academic project, so eventhough I do have some gestures in mind, I don't think I can just say "Yeah I chose this because I felt that's good" as the reason why I design that gesture. So, is there any known principle, guidance, consensus, or standard in designing hand gesture?

This is my first time asking here, if there's any mistake or I asked in wrong place, please do tell me.

Comment: It will be impossible to answer unless you tell us what the gesture is used for.

Comment: I see. Actually I intentionally left it 'general' like that because I wanna see many usages, but turns out it's not a good idea. Thanks Sir, I've edited it, adding more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a gesture recognition software has to be very intuitive to a human and what you gesture should be indicative of the action you want to perform. Thus you can see that most gesture recognition software out there try to emulate sign language or borrow gestures from it to perform actions.

So in your case for going to the previous screen you can gesture "going back". This link might give you some ways to show previous: 
http://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-signs/b/back.htm

Most commonly used gestures in gesture recognition software include

- clenching/grabbing motion : for selection
- clenching and going back : to zoom out
- clenching and going forward : to zoom in
- move hand sideways : to move through screens/navigate

... just to name a few. So I'd suggest you to find the equivalent sign language representation of the action you want to perform and use it.