# Principle in Motion/Hand Motion Design

Tags: website-design, gestures

Basically, this is the same with my previous question:
[Principle in Hand Gesture Design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57581/principle-in-hand-gesture-design), but now for Motion.

I want to design Motion. By motion, I mean the movement may be made by human, like 'move to the right', 'moving hand to the right or left', etc. I design it to be tested on a UI like webpage, e.g. 'moving hand up-down' for 'scrolling'.

So, is there any known principle, guidance, consensus, or standard in designing motion? Or, since it's related to human body, say it needs to be natural, but how to know what's natural what's not, what's the standard should be used?

In case I ask in wrong place or there's lack of information, please tell me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do some research on existing patterns. XBox Kinect, Playstation Move, and Leap Motion are all good places to start.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I don't know Playstation Move, but I've searched Kinect and Leap Motion. User can design their own gesture, can't they? Then what pattern is it that I have to search?

Comment: By pattern I mean "series of interactions with an overarching structure or theme."  An example of a common desktop UI pattern is the slide-out/hamburger menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best rule of thumb when designing intuitive interactions is to think about how someone would interact with your UI if it was composed of real world objects.

As SwankyLegg pointed out, much of the work may already be done. I saw a Microsoft presentation a few years ago on how they researched, designed, and tested touch and movement gestures. They did put a lot of effort into finding gestures that were intuitive and easy for novice users to discover, and did a lot of usability testing. Much of what they have done can help you with standard navigation gestures.

If you are starting completely from scratch in designing specific gestures, then try building a physical model of your UI and watch what movements people make when interacting with the controls. Then verify the gestures with as much usability testing as you have resources for. If you are stretched, even just getting friends and family to try it should give you some useful insights.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thinking, thinking and prolonged searching, I found that it seems for my level, I'm so very arrogant if I want to propose a new gesture, so for now I think I'll focus my research on testing existing gesture applied to webpage. But your suggestion is very true! In one point I reached thinking "what if I applied it to real object? What gesture myself will do?", and when I tried it to my family, they also made a more or less the same gesture as me. And then seeing your post made me feel relieved, because I felt like "ah so that's the right step!". Thank you very much!

Comment: @zargin Glad I could be of some help :)